# Checking content of textbox vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, textbox, user-input

I am using a text box for input to my SQL query. Based on the input I create a certain query and display the data in a gridview.

However I wish to make an adjustment for my users.

They often make an input like PL26... However this is not a valid name in the database to search for. Therefore I want to CHECK their input, and alter it accordingly, so they don't have to think about it.

I happen to know that when they type PL26 the correct input would be PL000026 ... The entity to search for is always "PL" + 6 characters/numbers... so if they wrote PL155, the number/string I pass to the sql query should become PL + 000 + 155 = PL000155.

I hope someone can help me how to accomplish this. That is if it is possible?

My idea/Pseudo code would be something like

```
If tbInput.txt's FIRST 2 CHARS are PL, then check total length of string
     if StringLength < 8 characters, then 
            if length = 2 then ADD 4 0' after PL...
                if length = 3 then add 3 0's after  PL...
                    if length = 3 then add 3 0's after  PL..  
              etc
                 ....
                   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
  Private Sub Button21_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button21.Click

        Debug.Print(formatCode("PL1"))
        Debug.Print(formatCode("PL"))
        Debug.Print(formatCode("PL01"))
        Debug.Print(formatCode("PL155"))


    End Sub

    Private Function formatCode(userInput As String) As String

        Dim returnVal As String
        If userInput.Length < 8 Then
            returnVal = String.Concat(userInput.Substring(0, 2), userInput.Substring(2, userInput.Length - 2).PadLeft(6, "0"))
        Else
            returnVal = userInput
        End If

        Return returnVal

    End Function
```

You may need to add some validation ensuring it starts with PL etc.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work as long as there are no other non-numeric characters in between the PL and the numbers. You can always add it in your validation.

```
Dim newInput As String

If (input.StartsWith("PL")) Then
    input = input.Remove(0, 2)
End If

' If this fails then it means the input was not valid
Dim numberPart = Convert.ToInt32(input)

newInput = "PL" + numberPart.ToString("D6")
```

Comment: Hello Von v, thankyou very much for your reply! This was a simple and good solution that works just perfectly...!

Comment: Glad it was perfect for your situation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Exctract a number by removing prefix "PL"
Parse to Integer
Use [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.80).aspx)(zero placeholder) for adding zeros and prefix

```
Const PREFIX As String = "PL"
Dim exctractedNumber As Int32
If Int32.TryParse(tbInput.txt.Replace(PREFIX, String.Empty), exctractedNumber) = False Then
    'Error nahdling
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim finalFormat As String = String.Format("'{0}'000000", PREFIX)
Dim finalValue As String = exctractedNumber.ToString(finalFormat)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the handy PadLeft method:

```
Dim input As String = "PL26"
Dim number As String = input.Substring(2, input.Length - 2)

If number.Length <> 6 Then
    number = number.PadLeft(6, "0"C)
End If
```

[MSDN String.PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)